# Apple TV Resolution in Full HD

Tags: appletv

Is Apple TV Full HD?

I need to stream video to my TV wirelessly, but necessarly need to be Full HD to use all the TV resolution.

I think Apple TV is not Full HD, but I don't know if it exist some hardware like it, with same features, but that supports Full HD. What your recommend?

I've researched if Apple is planning to release Apple TV that supports Full HD but I found nothing about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apple TV is full HD, this is why you can rent and view full HD films and video content.

However if you are streaming from an iPad, and the video on the iPad is not HD the the content streamed to the TV will not be HD.

---

Edit

This applies to the previous version of the Apple TV with a built in HD. not the current one. [Here is a comparison of the two](http://www.digitaltrends.com/home-theater/new-apple-tv-vs-old-apple-tv-whats-changed/).

Comment: Graeme, where do you saw that Apple TV is Full HD.

Comment: @EdPichler http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/news/comments/apple-tv-20-update-now-available/

Comment: @Greme and if my source was an Macbook streaming Full HD content?

Comment: as long as the video you were streaming is saved as a compatabile HD video then it will be fine. If you are in the USA it will be NTSC or the UK and Europe PAL.

I have also edited the answer to avoid confusion over the models of Apple TV

Comment: I read it. So, it seems it uses upscaling to play Full HD =[

Comment: Yes, this means if the content is not 1080p it will upscale so that it is.

Answer (score 2):

The AppleTV outputs in 720p and can't officially play 1080p content but it will attempt to if given 1080p content.  The only good source of 1080p content is blu-ray, anything streamed on the internet today can't match blu-ray...yet.

Answer (score 2):

The third-generation Apple TV released in early March, 2012 is definitely Full HD (1080p).

Answer (score 1):

Much like "Lite" and "Risk Free", "Full HD" is a marketing term that does not have a formal definition.  Apple TV generates a signal to the television in a maximum of 720p which is probably not what you're hoping for.